# Vysor stuck on "Waiting for decoder"

Tags: android, vysor

I'm trying to use Vysor to show my app on the PC. However, after installing and launching Vysor it just gets stuck on "Waiting for decoder" semi-black screen.

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find anyone else with this problem.

[image: Vysor problem]

Comment: any fix for this?

Answer (score 15):

Resetting the Vysor works for me.

Advanced Option in Vysor --> click on Reset vysor.

Comment: "Advanced" is located at bottom of VYSOR's home screen

Comment: Greate answer. It worked

Answer (score 5):

Solution for this problem

1. Click on setting icon from vysore screen
   [image]
2. Click on setting menu.
3. in lower bottom, click on "defaults" bitton
   [image]
4. Click on save button.

Problem should get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

[Go to the settings[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8pEg.png) (It is in the top of the screen - gear icon you will find)

In the Image quality section select the Decoder as web assembly.